# What confines atmosphere around earth?

Tags: atmospheric-science

Exactly the title. There needs to be a pressure to prevent gases from perpetually expanding, right? Bear with me, I'm not a physicist or studying to be one.

Comment: One word explanation: Gravity.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably not a valid stack-exchange question since the answer is available online just by doing a Google search, but the answer is gravity. That's why gas giants are largely gaseous, and the tiny Moon has virtually no atmosphere, and the Earth is somewhere in between.

Comment: Concise and precise, without too much depth. Good answer!

Comment: It is a valid question, it's not necessarily easy to google if one doesn't know what keywords to search for.

Comment: what about solar wind and temperature in less gravity planets ?